# Вопросительные предложения с однородными членами

Tags: пунктуация

В справочнике Лопатина есть такие строки: "При смысловом подчеркивании отдельных членов вопросительного предложения знаки препинания ставятся после каждого из членов, которые оформляются как самостоятельная синтаксическая единица, т. е. начинаются с прописной буквы: *— Что вас привело к ним? — неожиданно бытовым, ворчливым голосом спросил он. — Недомыслие? Страх? Голод? (А. Т.); — Где же те силы, которые питают национальный дух и делают русского русским, узбека узбеком, а немца немцем? Природа? Среда обитания? Вообще среда? Язык? Предания? История? Религия? Литература и вообще искусство? И что тут стоит на первом месте? (Сол.).*
Интересно: какое оформление считается нормативным в случае, когда смысловое подчеркивание отсутствует. Неужели "Что вас привело к ним: недомыслие, страх, голод?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что вас привело к ним: недомыслие, страх, голод?

Предложение не вызывает особых вопросов, это однородные подлежащие, поясняющие обобщающее слово с вопросительным значением.

Стоит обратить внимание на его интонацию. Повышение тона на слове ЧТО, затем понижение тона после двоеточия, далее повышение тона на каждом однородном члене.

Таким образом, обобщающее слово и однородные члены повышением тона выделяются интонационно в единую группу, что связывает их между собой и соответствует вопросительному характеру предложения.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.